# What is a rigorous definition for "subspace"?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, definition

I learned that the subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ can only be the origin or a $\mathbb R$ space that pass through the origin.

I also learned that the subspace of $X$ is any subset that contains an open set.

The two definitions seem to be contradictory.

My question is, what is rigorous definition for subspace?

Comment: A subspace $U\subset V$ of a vector space $V$ is a priori a subset of $V$ but it needs to be itself a vector space when equipped with addition and scalar multiplication inherited from $V$. A sufficient condition for this to hold is that 1) $U$ must be non empty and 2) linear combinations of elements in $U$ are contained in $U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, what is rigorous definition for subspace?

The word "subspace" on its own doesn't mean much and depends on the context. It can mean:

1. Topological subspace: any subset with [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology)
2. Metric subspace: any subset with metric restricted to it
3. Linear subspace: a subset closed under addition and scalar multiplication
4. ...

and more. One could use the same term for normed, Banach, inner product, Hilbert, affine, measurable, probability subspaces. Even schemes or topoi. The list is just huge, close to endless.

All those have precise definitions, often unrelated to other structures. And so you need to understand the context, in order to understand what "subspace" means.

> I learned that the subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ can only be the origin or a $\mathbb R$ space that pass through the origin.

Here, the author most likely refers to linear subspace. Note that $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself is also a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> I also learned that the subspace of $X$ is any subset that contains an open set.

Unlikely anyone defined "subspace" like that. In the context of metric and/or topology, the term "subspace" literally means any subset. Subset that contain an open subset are typically called a subset with nonempty interior.

Answer (score 2):

Being a subspace depends on some kind of space of which you can be a subspace. Therefore there are very many different definitions of subspaces depending on your setup.

You can take sub (vector) spaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which gives you (up to you not mentioning the entire space as a subspace of itself) the subspaces that you mentioned at first.

If you consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a topological/metric space, you can also consider (topological/metric) subspaces of it. These will once again be topological/metric spaces and do not have to be sub vector spaces at all.

There are nevertheless very general definitions of what it means to a "subsomething", but I would not suggest you to think about this level of generality at this point.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Are there any sources that I can get expose to what it mean by "subsomething"? Are you referring to categorical theory?

Comment: Any source on basics of category theory. The right notion is the notion of a subobject of a given object in a category. I still doubt that this level of generality is useful to you though. Let me nevertheless explain the idea. The idea is that you want a subset which happens to have the same kind of structure (group/ring/vector space/topological space/...) so that the inclusion map is a structure preserving map (group hom/ring hom/linear map/continuous map/...). This is formalized in terms of a general notion of equivalence classes of monomorphisms in category theory.

Comment: @RobertMuller - Is there a similar notion of equivalence classes of general morphisms (not monomorphisms)? In the category of finite sets, I think these would be multisets, for example.

Comment: Sure. The equivalence relation is "up to isomorphism of the domain", which is also something you can consider on general morphisms. It does give you isomorphism classes of morphisms (with fixed choice of target) then. For sets/finite sets this just reduces to the cardinality of the domain as the isomorphisms are exactly the bijections.

Comment: It's more than just cardinality. The two functions $\{0,1\}\to\{0,1\}$ given by $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=0$ have the same domain cardinality $2$, but there is no bijection $h:\{0,1\}\to\{0,1\}$ such that $f=g\circ h$.

Comment: So, does this notion of "morphism modulo isomorphism of the domain" have a name, or have you actually seen it before I mentioned it?

Comment: @mr_e_man you are right, of course... in my head I was still using injective maps where such phenomena cannot occur. Now that I think about it I see why you were mentioning multisets. Everything depends on how often elements in the target are hit.

Comment: I have not seen a particular name for this. The kind of things we want here are the isomorphisms in the slice category over the fixed target, but this is also not really a name, but rather a different point of view. But I guess thats the best I can come up with right now.